# Finder windows won't show after reinstlling Mavericks ower Yosemite

Tags: finder, macos

I have recently reinstalled Mavericks and found that I couldn't launch finder anymore. When I click on the finder icon on the dock, double click on desktop folders or try to open recycle bin, nothing happens.

I tried to find solutions online, and tried the following methods. None of them works.

1. force relaunch
2. repair permissions
3. delete the ~Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist